# How to save data to user session in Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

After I log in the user on the backend (I use Parse.com CloudCode) I would like to save the uri to his avatar in his session. 
How would I do it in Parse.com. I know there is an object [Parse.Session.current()](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Session.html) but not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat it just like other objects provided by parse.

```
Parse.Session.current().then(function(session) {
    session.set("foo", "bar");
    session.save().then(function() {
        console.log(session.get("foo"));
    });
});
```

The session CLP should be set to allow this.  (And the app must be setup to require revokable sessions).

Comment: when I try this I get an error the `session object` does not have a method `set`. and when I do `JSON.stringify(session)` I get the following JSON `{"_resolved":false,"_rejected":false,"_resolvedCallbacks":[],"_rejectedCallbacks":[]}`

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  It needs to be fetched asynchronously.  Please see edit.